# Flask Assets bundles not compiling when run under uWSGI

Tags: flask, uwsgi, webassets, flask-assets

They run normally when I run the flask app directly but don't compile or replace the address in the template when run under uWSGI.

How can I debug this?

EDIT:

code:
    assets = Environment(app)

```
...

if __name__ == "__main__":        
    assets.register(YAMLLoader(os.path.join(DIR,"assets.yml")).load_bundles())

    if os.environ.get("DEBUG_FLASK"):
        app.run()
    else:
        app.run(debug=True)
```

assets.yml:

```
style_css:
    filters: less
    output: css/style.css
    contents:
        - css/style.less
```

Comment: Check the permissions to the output path. Also, you can get some output from your logs. Check them.

Comment: Turns out it was file permissions for me thanks @iurisilvio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out uwsgi does its own thing with app variable to run the webapp and doesn't run the script as __main__ so

```
assets.register(YAMLLoader(os.path.join(DIR,"assets.yml")).load_bundles())
```

never got called. I moved it out of the

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
```

block. And it worked.